# React native unexpected token

Tags: react-native

I have just started learning react native.

Tried use style for NavigatorIOS, but I get unexpected token error here `style={{styles.tabBarStyle}}` What am I doing wrong?

Only works if I inline paste style in tag.

full code:

```
http://pastebin.com/NpdSWL6k
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be `style={styles.tabBarStyle}` instead of `style={{styles.tabBarStyle}}` . If you are using inline style then your list style should be object in itself.

Comment: Work. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should write

```
<SomeComponent 
    style={styles.tabBarStyle} 
</SomeComponent>
```

JS code should be written inside **one** set of curly braces and **not two** like you wrote. The second set of curly braces means Object type so this :

```
{styles.tabBarStyle}
```

is not a valid Object. That is why you get this error.